# Is there a graph api that sends message from channel/team to individual person?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am looking for a solution where a team can contact a single user via chat.

Adding that user to the team and then removing could be a possible solution - but not that good. Also, if team A wants to connect person B and person C separately.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Teams allows users to bring bots into their channel or group chat conversations. By adding a bot to a team or chat, all users of the conversation can take advantage of the bot functionality right in the conversation. You can also access Teams-specific functionality within your bot like querying team information and @mentioning users.
Chat in channels and group chats differ from personal chat in that the user needs to @mention the bot.

Please refer below doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conv-channel